# BYFN.sh failed with error when setting up MSP of type bccsp

Tags: macos, go, hyperledger-fabric, demo

I am trying the first-network demo on OS X and am getting the following error.  I have tried searching for an answer.  I did found one here but it appears that is for Ubuntu.  All the commands didn't work on OS X.

Can anyone suggest a solution on OS X?  Thanks!

> 2018-11-02 03:13:45.696 UTC [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer
>   because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory
>   /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp:
>   could not initialize BCCSP Factories: Failed initializing PKCS11.BCCSP
>   %!s(): Could not initialize BCCSP PKCS11 [Failed to initialize
>   software key store: An invalid KeyStore path provided. Path cannot be
>   an empty string.] !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed
>   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>   ========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ==========

Comment: What version of Hyperledger Fabric are you trying to run?.  Most likely your problem has nothing to do with the fact of running it on OSX

Comment: I am running 1.3.  I am guessing there is something with not being able to find the path to the keystone.  But I am not sure how to fix it.  Wish there were more support available.

Comment: The only related link I could find about your error is this issue: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-8853.  The issue was about expired certificates but as you are using the latest version I guess that will not help.  Did you tried to remove everything you installed and start from scratch with the previous version:

curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.2.1 1.2.1 0.4.10

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not very specific.

In my case, I was trying to connect to a peer from my fabric-tools container, and there was a TLS enabled mismatch (fabric-tools has TLS enabled, and fabric-peer had TLS disabled). Aligning the TLS configuration made the error go away.

Might help someone out...